# How to access a HTML table's ID ("not asp:Table") in C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I tried accessing using `runat="server"` which helped but by putting it in the table an error occurs which wont let me to run the application. The error I get is

> "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRowCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow)' has some invalid arguments".

```
    <table id="supp_table" class="table">
                                    <thead class=" text-primary">
                                        <th>
                                            ID
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Email
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Address
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Phone No.
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Added BY
                                        </th>                                        
                                    </thead>

                                    <tbody runat ="server">
                                        <%=getSupplierData()%>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: Please share your relevant  html and c# code. And tell us which line gives you error?

Comment: I have provided the relevant HTML code of the table. I just need to access this table's id in C#.

Comment: Think about what you're saying. A plain HTML table is just included in the HTML sent to the client. There is no manipulating it from C#. You would need to add the `runat="server"` attribute if you wanted to convert it to a server side control. Always keep in mind the separation between server and client side. If you're going to use Web Forms (and I strongly reccomend you don't) then you're far better off converting it to an `asp:Table`.

Comment: I tried using the runat="server" attribute but when I add this to the table, the application wont run because of the error mentioned above.